# Update photo with delay

Tags: android

I am new to programming and I have struggled with this for days and cannot get it to work.

I have a loop to execute some tasks. It will display a picture in an `ImageView` for that particular task. So it goes something like this:

- setImageResource
- do some task
- wait for 1 second
- then start everything again until the commands end
- when all commands end, close that activity by calling finish()

I tried to use a handler with runnable and asynctask but I cannot get it to work. The UI is always updated later than the 1 second delay. As I call finish() after the commands ends, the photo seems not show up at all.

```
for(int i=0; i<actions.size(); i++) {
            switch((int)actions.get(i)[0]) {
            case 0:
                ivActionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
                sleeping=true;
                DelayAsyncTask delay=new DelayAsyncTask();
                delay.execute();
                while(sleeping){};
                break;
            }
        }
        finish();
class DelayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        sleeping=false;
    }

}
```

I am using a variable "sleeping" to let the main thread to wait for the delay.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and any logcat errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from taking a guess this loop is somewhere in a UI thread.  That means that you are blocking the UI thread until the async finishes.  That is a NO-NO!  Why not just update the image in the onPostExecute?  Something like

```
class DelayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ivActionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);
    }
```

obviously remove this line of code as well (I don't think I ever know a reason for doing something like that anyway).

```
while(sleeping){};
```

Comment: Yes, the loop is in the UI thread. I understand it is not good. But what I want to do it to read an action, display that action image for 500ms, execute that action and then go back to the loop for the next action. That is the "while(sleeping){};" is for. If there is no action in the loop, I want to close the activity. That's why I don't want to update the new image in the onPostExecute, because it make me out of the loop.

Comment: you should NOT be executing this in the UI thread, it can cause Android to force close your app.  You should move the whole loop to an asynctask (or maybe a few for each task).  As long as the asynctask is inline then you can finish() the activity when everything is done.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I put the loop in the doInBackground and I update the UI using progressUpdate. It is working fine now.

Comment: @yotyotsclee4 my pleasure.  Good luck with the rest of the app.